# How can I simulate mouse events from code?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mouse, mouseevent

I would like to simulate mouse events using the Win32 API; how can I do it?

What I want to do is simulate the event at the most basic level, the level at which the system has just the event type and the co-ordinates and hasn't yet figured which window it must relay it to.

I don't know if that's how things work. Either way, I need help doing it. Would I have to meddle at the driver level?!

To make my requirements clear, I don't want to target any window, I just want the system to think the mouse was clicked or moved by the user. And I would be coding in C.

Answer (score 30):

You're looking for the [**`SendInput`** function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx), which allows you to synthesize mouse 
movements and button clicks in your code by specifying an array of [`INPUT` structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646270.aspx) corresponding to input events.

```
UINT WINAPI SendInput(
  __in  UINT nInputs,     // number of structures in the pInputs array
  __in  LPINPUT pInputs,  // an array of INPUT structures, representing an event
  __in  int cbSize        // the size, in bytes, of an INPUT structure
);
```

Note, however, that this function is subject to [User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation), which means that your application is only permitted to inject input to applications that are running at an equal or lesser integrity level.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the `integrity level` giving my application admin rights solved that problem for me :)

Answer (score 6):

Use `mouse_event` (winuser.h).  The following code will move the mouse then perform a click at the new location. You can do this in two lines but this is more verbose.

Note that X and Y are specified in [mickeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), 0 to 65535.  This is then mapped onto the current resolution, i.e. 0,0 will be the top left corner and 65535,65535 will be the lower right hand corner.

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, x, y, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: According to [MSDN's docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260.aspx), mouse_event has been superseded by SendInput.  They recommend using SendInput instead.

Comment: The mouse_event function doesn't seem to work on Windows 10, Cody's SendInput method does, though.