# WM_MOUSEMOVE - packing x and y positions

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am using a crude system to control a Flash movie from a C++/win32 program by sending WM_MOUSEMOVE events directly to the Flash window.

It works well for one axis:

```
SendMessage( m_targetWindowHWND, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, xpos);
```

However I'd like to now send both x and y values. I know these are packed into a WM_MOUSEMOVEs lparam. In C++ this could be unpacked with MAKEPOINTS or GET_X_LPARAM/GET_Y_LPARAM.

But how do I pack the x and y, basically doing the reverse of the macros above.

My guess:

```
DWORD packed = y << 8 + x;
```

Thanks

Comment: They are 16 bit words, shift by 16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro you're looking for is `MAKELPARAM`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661(v=vs.85).aspx

```
LPARAM WINAPI MAKELPARAM(
    WORD wLow,
    WORD wHigh
);
```

I believe it's equivalent to `MAKELONG` (same thing but returns a `DWORD`), but then again...maybe there's a platform out there where a LPARAM and a DWORD are defined differently.  :-/

---

**EDIT**: Apparently LPARAM (and WPARAM!) are nowadays both defined under the hood to be the size of pointers on your platform.  The "L" (long) and "W" (word) are historical: [What are the definitions for LPARAM and WPARAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515261/what-are-lparam-and-wparam-defined-as)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Microsoft provided macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632661.aspx):

```
MAKELPARAM(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be simple!