# How do I simulate a single click on Windows and Linux using C?

Tags: c, click, mouseevent, simulation

What libraries should I use?

What documentation am I supposed to read?

Maybe someone could drop a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, if you want to simulate a mouse click inside a specific window, the relevant window messages are the following (link to documentation included):

[WM_LBUTTONDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown)

[WM_LBUTTONUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttonup)

[WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondblclk) (on second click, this message is sent instead of WM_LBUTTONDOWN)

To simulate a mouse click, you can send a window any of these window messages, using the [PostMessage()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea) function.

For this function, you require a window handle (HWND) for the target window. This can be obtained for example using the [EnumWindows()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows) or [FindWindow()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) function.

However, if you want to simulate a mouse click on the screen instead of inside a specific window, then you will have to use the [SendInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function. For further details, see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164774/how-can-i-simulate-mouse-events-from-code).

Also, be aware that since Windows Vista, for security reasons, it is not possible anymore to send processes with administrative privileges messages from non-privileged processes.

The above information only applies to Windows. Unfortunately, I can't help you with Linux, but you may find the solution in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595716/control-mouse-by-writing-to-dev-input-mice).